# Creating 2D array using file pointer

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I wrote this program that creates a 2D array from an input file and then does various things to the numbers, like calculate average, get max, etc...
The input file has 96 characters, 12 rows of 8 characters each. This is exactly how I want to set up the array.

I feel like everything is correct with the exception of creating the array. When I run the function to print the array, some really funky numbers pop up, including negatives. Far from what is in the input file.

Can anyone see something wrong in the makeArray function or in how I'm calling the function in main?

```
#include <stdio.h>        
void makeArray(FILE*ptr, int array[12][8]) {
    int i,j;
    ptr = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++) {
            fscanf(ptr, "%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }   
}

int getScore(int array[12][8], int mon, int trn) {      
    return array[mon][trn];
}

int getMonthMax(int array[12][8], int mon) {
    int max = 0, i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
        if (array[mon][i]>max)
            max = array[mon][i];
    }
    return max;
}

int getYearMax(int array[12][8]) {
    int max = 0, i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] > max)
                max = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int getMonthAvg(int array[12][8], int mon) {
    int avg, sum = 0, i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
        sum = array[mon][i] + sum;
    }
    avg = sum / 8;
    return avg;
}

int getYearAvg(int array[12][8]) {
    int avg, sum=0, i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++) {
            sum = array[i][j] + sum;
        }
    }
    avg = sum / (12 * 8);
    return avg;
}

int toursMissed(int array[12][8]) {
    int count = 0, i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == 0)
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


void printArray (int array[12][8]) {
    int i, j;
    printf("The scores for the year are:\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void displayMenu() {
    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Select from options 1-7 or 0 to stop\n");
    printf("Select 1 to get the score for a specific game\n");
    printf("Select 2 to get the max score for a specific month\n");
    printf("Select 3 to get the average score for a specific month\n");
    printf("Select 4 to get the max score for the year\n");
    printf("Select 5 to get the average score for the year\n");
    printf("Select 6 to get the number of tournaments missed for the year\n");
    printf("Select 7 to print all scores for the year\n");
    printf("Select 0 to stop\n");
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
}

void processRequest(int array[12][8], int num) {
    int scores[12][8], answ, mon, game;

    if (num == 0) {
        printf("Thank you! Goodbye.");
    }       
    else if (num == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the month and the game\n");
        scanf("%d%d", &mon, &game);
        answ= getScore(scores, mon, game);
        printf("The score for Tournament %d is %d\n\n\n\n", game, answ);
    }
    else if (num == 2) {
        printf("Please enter the month\n");
        scanf("%d", &mon);
        answ=getMonthMax(scores, mon);
        printf("The maximum score for month %d is %d\n\n\n\n", mon, answ);  
    }
    else if (num == 3) {
        printf("Please enter the month\n");
        scanf("%d", &mon);
        answ=getMonthAvg(scores, mon);
        printf("The average score for month %d is %d\n\n\n\n", mon, answ);
    }
    else if (num == 4) {
        answ= getYearMax(scores);   
        printf("The max score for the year is %d\n\n\n\n", answ);
    }
    else if (num == 5) {
        answ= getYearAvg(scores);
        printf("The average score for the year is %d\n\n\n\n", answ);
    }               
    else if (num == 6) {
        answ= toursMissed(scores);
        printf("The number of tournaments missed for the year is %d\n\n\n\n", answ);
    }       
    else if (num == 7) {
        printArray(scores);
        printf("\n\n\n\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Please make a valid selection\n\n\n\n");   
}

int main() {
    int choice;
    int scores[12][8];

    FILE *input;
    makeArray(input, scores);

    do {
        displayMenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        processRequest(scores, choice);    
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of the input file?

Answer (score -2):

First. You should allocate memory for each raw in array

```
int ii;
typedef FILE * FILE_PTR;
FILE_PTR ** lossArr = (FILE_PTR**)malloc( sizeof( FILE_PTR* ) * i );
for ( ii = 0; ii < i; ii++ ) {
    lossArr[ ii ] = (FILE_PTR*)malloc( sizeof( FILE_PTR ) * j );
}
// now you can use lossArr[ x ][ y ], where x = 0..i-1, y = 0..j-1
```

Comment: I see how that works, but unfortunately this is for an assignment so I cannot use things out of the material. I need to use just about what I did use throughout the program

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`.